# Is possible (or a good idea) to share ISessionFactory between WCF services hosted in the same IIS application?

Tags: wcf, nhibernate

I have several WCF services hosted in the same IIS application, using per session binding.  All those services uses the same database.  I'm using Unity for DI means, and registering the session factory as singleton (`ContainerControlledLifeTimeManager`).  I'm using the NHibernate 3 `WcfSessionContext`.

I had troubles with my services, because when one service was called the session factory registered with a previous service simply switched the context (the previous service called get without session factory registered in his context).

I managed to resolve the issue using a shared dictionary of session factories, thus each service has his own session factory, all of them aiming to the same database.

This make me think that perhaps would be better to have one single session factory for all this WCF services, but I don't know if this is possible or if is preferrable to have a session factory per service despite all of them are using the same underliyng database.

As a side note, those services had been working fine with the same session factory in the console host version.  Only when deployed in IIS the problems arised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have one single SessionFactory for all Services. SessionFactory is thread safe. You can put it to static field then , inject a deletage factory that always returns the very same SessionFactory. Actually instead of injecting the SessionFactory, you'd better inject ISession itself.